# Generating an elf header

Tags: elf, executable, binary-format

To get a basic understanding of the [ELF format](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/elf.pdf), I'm writing a basic program to generate a valid elf file from the most basic assembly output. I'm going step-by-step so I'll probably ask a few questions here as I make my way through it. I've generated the first 16-bytes of the header and verified that it's the same from a gcc-compiled program on my machine (nothing special, since those first 16-bytes are almost always the same). Here is what I have so far (using python):

```
# https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/elf.pdf
b = bytearray()

# (1) magic header
b.append(0x7F) # starting number
b.extend([ord('E'), ord('L'), ord('F')])

# (2) ei-class ('capacity') -- 1 for 32-bit, 2 for 64-bit
# uname -m # x86_64
BITS_32 = 1
BITS_64 = 2
b.append(BITS_64)

# (3) ei-data ('data-encoding') -- 1 for little-endian (standard), 2 for big-endian
LITTLE_ENDIAN = 1
BIG_ENDIAN    = 2
b.append(LITTLE_ENDIAN)

# (4) ei-version -- always will be 1 -- 
EV_CURRENT = 1
b.append(EV_CURRENT)

# (5) ei-pad -- padding --> pad 0's up to 16 bytes
b.extend([0,] * (16-len(b)))

print('%s\nLength: %s' % (b, len(b)))
```

And I get:

```
bytearray(b'\x7fELF\x02\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
Length: 16
```

I have a few questions about this:

- What is the most common way to get whether a machine is `32` or `64` bits? Is doing `uname -m` or one of the `uname` variants the suggested way?
- How do you determine if the machine is little- or big-endian?

Comment: for python, why not use the `platform` module?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik oh, and even if not, it mentions all the ways it gathers the data so I can use that: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/platform.py.

Comment: Which machine? The host machine you are developing software on? Or the target of the ELF binary? If you want details about the environment you are working in, you can use utility programs or a language's library functions as mentioned by Paweł and Shane.  As currently written, it's not clear what this question has to do with the ELF format or reverse engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux machines, the `lscpu` command will tell you both the endianness of the CPU and whether it is 32/64 bit.